# Last vs last for with time

Tags: prepositions, time, formal-language, time-reference

In the Moscow aeroexpress train to Domodedovo airport I heard an announcement, "**The trip will last for 45 minutes**" and I wonder if **for** is optional in announcements. Is it said the same way in London for instance? Is it a formal way?

I know we can say, "**The trip will last 45 minutes**". Is it any different from **last for**?

Comment: Not really any difference in meaning or formality. It’s just an optional preposition.

Comment: If there is a slight difference in register, the version without **for** is the more colloquial/conversational of the two.  You'd probably see the prepositional phrase in a text that was aiming for something a tad more polished than impromptu conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to favour no "for", since *last* takes a timespan as a direct object, much like *take* does:

> The trip will last 45 minutes.
>
> A rose lasts only a little while.
>
> A journey to Mars on the new shuttle would still take years.

However, you do hear *last for X amount of time* now and again, and it shows up in books, sometimes with [more frequency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lasted%20for%20months%2Clasted%20months&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clasted%20for%20months%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clasted%20months%3B%2Cc0) and sometimes with [less](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=last%20a%20year%20%2B%20last%20a%20day%2Clast%20for%20a%20year%20%2B%20last%20for%20a%20day&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28last%20a%20year%20%2B%20last%20a%20day%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28last%20for%20a%20year%20%2B%20last%20for%20a%20day%29%3B%2Cc0).

This usage with *for* is probably because *last* is also an intransitive verb. Any verb can have its duration specified in that way:

> He played golf for five days straight.
>
> She will go camping for three months.

Here, the amount of time is not objective, but adverbial.

(This would also explain why you can't say "It takes for an X amount of time": unlike *last*,  *take* has no intransitive variant.)

Comment: It all depends on how the question is posed. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lasted+for+months%2Clasted+months&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clasted%20for%20months%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clasted%20months%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Edited to be wholly more circumspect.